# Is there a way to cluster multiple groups of strings by similarity?

Tags: cluster-analysis, dna-sequence, mutation

I have next-generation sequencing data for several patients (Patient1, Patient2, Patient3...).

Patient samples can be from the same disease or different diseases. We know that the incidence of certain mutations are higher in certain diseases, some variants are disease causing, others are associated to the disease and we don't really know how they contribute to the disease etc. 
I'm looking for a way to cluster these patients based on the altered genes to see if there's any common traits... One gene may have several alterations (e.g. NRAS G12D vs. NRAS G13D vs. NRAS Q61K ...). The order of the altered genes in a given patient shouldn't matter. A typical finding in one patient is around 500 alterations and the number of patients is around a hundred.

I checked the previous posts, the question was about clustering strings composing one list, this is between multiple lists of strings rather.

Thank you for your your help.

Data for one patient is like this:

```
    #Patient1
    chromosome <- c("X",    "7",    "10",   "1",    "X",    "5",    "5",    "X",    "10",   "7")
    position <- c("70360589","128829066","89692923","11206853","70360680","176637576","176637471","70360648","89692913","148543694")
    reference <- c("AGC","A","G","AC","GCA","T","G","CAG","G","AA")
    alter <- c("","G","A","","","C","A","","A","")
    gene <- c("MED12","SMO","PTEN","MTOR","MED12","NSD1","NSD1","MED12","PTEN","EZH2")
    cdot <- c("c.6165_6167delGCA","c.74A>G","c.407G>A","c.4571-6_4571-5delGT","c.6256_6258delCAG","c.2176T>C","c.2071G>A","c.6226_6228delCAG","c.397G>A","c.118-5_118-4delTT")
    pdot <- c("Q2076del","D25G","C136Y"," ","Q2086del","S726P","A691T","Q2076del","V133I"," ")
    patient1 <- data.frame(chromosome, position, reference, alter, gene, cdot, pdot)
```

A mutation can be represented in different ways, gene with cdot, gene with gdot, chromosome with ref and alter etc. The most convenient one for me is gene & pdot, as it's more informative since it tells me the altered gene and what's the atleration (e.g. PTEN is the gene, C25G means that the reference amino acid "C" at position 25 is altered to amino acid "G").

I tried to concatenate every pair of Gene&pdot in one string, so if the patient has 10 alterations, like in the data frame above, I'll have 10 strings. I'd do this for all the patients than cluster all the patients based on the alterations they have. My question is what's the best approach to cluster multiple patients in this example.

Two more patients:

```
    #Patient2
    chromosome <- c("X","6","1","1","6","12","5","X","1","10")
    position <- c("47424495","157100024","78429978","242023898","30858801","49427266","176637576","70360648","78435702","89692913")
    reference <- c("A","GGA","T","A","C","TGC","T","CAG","AA","G")
    alter <- c("","","","G","","","C","","","A")
    gene <- c("ARAF","ARID1B","FUBP1","EXO1","DDR1","KMT2D","NSD1","MED12","FUBP1","PTEN")
    cdot <- c("c.416delA","c.983_985delGAG","c.901delA","c.836A>G","c.474delC","c.11220_11222delGCA","c.2176T>C","c.6226_6228delCAG","c.121-4_121-3delTT","c.397G>A")
    pdot <- c("K139fs","G328del","I301fs","N279S","M159fs","Q3745del","S726P","Q2076del","","V133I")
    patient2 <- data.frame(chromosome, position,  reference, alter, gene, cdot, pdot)


    #Patient3
    chromosome <- c("1","2","11","14","14","12","2","19","12","17","X","1","10")
    position <- c("120539781","141259448","64572018","35871217","102551161","49426952","29416366","18273047","49426730","29490295","70360648","78435702","89692913")
    reference <- c("G","A","T","G","TCT","C","G","T","GCT","G","CAG","AA","G")
    alter <- c("A","","C","A","","T","C","C","","A","","","A")
    gene <- c("NOTCH2","LRP1B","MEN1","NFKBIA","HSP90AA1","KMT2D","ALK","PIK3R2","KMT2D","NF1","MED12","FUBP1","PTEN")
    cdot <- c("c.590C>T","c.8663-5delT","c.1621A>G","c.*2C>T","c.1202_1204delAGA","c.11536G>A","c.4587C>G","c.937T>C","c.11756_11758delAGC","c.380G>A","c.6226_6228delCAG","c.121-4_121-3delTT","c.397G>A")
    pdot <- c("T197I","","T541A","","K401del","G3846S","D1529E","S313P","Q3919del","G127E","Q2076del","","V133I")
    patient3 <- data.frame(chromosome, position,  reference, alter, gene, cdot, pdot)
```

In order to Make things simpler, I made up this example:

```
    #Simple Example
    modules1 <- c("maths", "physics", "geometry", "languages", "science", "geology")
    scores1 <- c("A+", "A", "A", "B+", "B", "B")
    student1 <- data.frame(modules1, scores1)
    modules2 <- c("music", "dance", "languages", "science")
    scores2 <- c("A+", "A+", "A+", "B")
    student2 <- data.frame(modules2, scores2)
    modules3 <- c("languages", "science", "physics", "maths")
    scores3 <- c("A+", "A+", "A+", "A")
    student3 <- data.frame(modules3, scores3)
```

How can I cluster students 1, 2 and 3 based on their scores.
I'd expect to have a dendrograme with stundents 1 & 3 closer to each other than student 2.

Comment: you have an interesting problem here. However, it lacks focus. I suggest the following changes in the question; (1) Provide the data type of variables. (2) Provide any pre-processing steps undertaken to reduce dimensionality (3) Do not throw in code, provide reasons on distance measure used for calculating the distance between variables. (4) Provide references to similar questions related to your problem. (5) Provide reasoning on why you chose a particular clustering algorithm for example in your current code, why you choose hierarchical clustering?

Comment: Thank you mnm for looking into this. I have edited my question and put some original data (not processed).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend encoding the data into a numerical format. Probably 1-hot coded since this is categorical data.

I would also keep the gene and mutation coding separate, since different mutations in the same gene may be equivalent.

For the following genes and mutations:

```
list_genes = [gene1, gene2, gene3]
list_disease = [disease1, disease2]
list_mutations_patient1 = [c25g, g149e, t543k]
list_mutations_patient2 = [a50g, "", t543k]
```

The first position in each list is a true-false for any mutation in the gene, the following positions are true-false for all the identified mutations in the data set, the last list (in each list of lists) is for the disease condition:

```
coded_list_gene_mutation_patient1 = [[1,1,0],[1,1],[1,1],[1,0]]
coded_list_gene_mutation_patient2 = [[1,0,1],[0,0],[1,1],[0,1]]
```

Flatten the lists and append all patient data

```
all_patient_lists = [1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1],[1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1]
```

Because the lists will likely be quite long, you should consider using dimentionality reduction (PCA or LDA or MDS).
You can then plot the first 2 or 3 components to see how well they partition the data and then pass the components from the PCA into a true clustering algorithm (rather than a partitioning algorithm) like hierarchical density based clustering (HDBScan),

This will assign each sample to a cluster provided a minimum number of members to form a cluster. Which is good if you expect some noise in the data (noise classified as outlier rather than being assigned to a cluster).

Answer (score -1):

I think you need `stringdist()`. The [strndist](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringdist/index.html) package offers ‘Approximate string matching and string distance functions’. It offers many algorithms but the one I'm using in this example is the **Jaro–Winkler distance** (Winkler, 1990) is a measure of similarity between two strings. The higher the Jaro–Winkler distance for two strings is, the more similar the strings are. The Jaro–Winkler distance metric is designed and best suited for short strings such as person names. The score is normalized such that 0 equates to no similarity and 1 is an exact match.

The 100 patients data can be merged into one dataframe. Borrowing from your above code, I'm extending it as;

```
## Lets merge all data frames into one
df.1<- merge(patient1, patient2 , all = TRUE)
df.master <- merge(df.1, patient3 , all = TRUE)
# replace missing entries with 0
df.master[is.na(df.master)] <- 0
head(df.master, 5)
  chromosome  position reference alter   gene                 cdot   pdot
1          1  11206853        AC         MTOR c.4571-6_4571-5delGT       
2          1 242023898         A     G   EXO1             c.836A>G  N279S
3          1  78429978         T        FUBP1            c.901delA I301fs
4          1  78435702        AA        FUBP1   c.121-4_121-3delTT       
5          1 120539781         G     A NOTCH2             c.590C>T  T197I
```

Now, lets measure the distance between the strings. Since, you mentioned that the interest lies in `gene` and `pdot` variable. Therefore, I'm using them as follows;

```
library(stringdist)

# find the unique genes
uniquegenes <- unique(as.character(df.master$pdot))
# determine the distance between various string using the Jar-Winkler distance
distancemodels <- stringdistmatrix(uniquegenes,uniquegenes,method = "jw")
rownames(distancemodels) <- uniquegenes
# Perform hierarchical clustering
hc <- hclust(as.dist(distancemodels))
# show the plot
plot(hc)
```

[image: Rplot-SOquestion-00]

```
# look at clusters
dfClust <- data.frame(uniquegenes, cutree(hc, k=4))
names(dfClust) <- c('gene_name','cluster')
print(paste('Average number of genes per cluster:', mean(table(dfClust$cluster))))
[1] "Average number of genes per cluster: 5.75"

# the average number of genes per cluster is 5. Lets look at these genes
t <- table(dfClust$cluster)
t <- cbind(t,t/length(dfClust$cluster))
t <- t[order(t[,2], decreasing=TRUE),]
p <- data.frame(factorName=rownames(t), binCount=t[,1], percentFound=t[,2])
dfClust <- merge(x=dfClust, y=p, by.x = 'cluster', by.y='factorName', all.x=T)
dfClust <- dfClust[rev(order(dfClust$binCount)),]
names(dfClust) <-  c('cluster','gene_name')
head (dfClust[c('cluster','gene_name')],5)
   cluster gene_name
12       1     S313P
11       1    M159fs
10       1     G127E
9        1      D25G
8        1    K139fs
```

Clearly cluster 1 is the largest holding most genes. Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm trying to cluster patients based on their variants, i.e. the cluster dendrogram branches should show patients, e.g. patient1 & patient2 in one branch as they're closer to each other than patient3 etc. Also, I have to add the gene name and not limit the clustering on the pdot, as it's very common to have the same reference amino acid at the same position for different genes but the mutation would have completely different effect.

Comment: One example is the pdot A146T is found in APC, HRAS, CD59, ATOH7 and KRAS genes. If I consider only pdot, all these genes will cluster together while they shouldn't.

Comment: @yysin use @ followed by the username to notify people when commenting. What you seek is very difficult for me to understand. Perhaps, you can break down the list of questions to simple meaningful sub questions and then ask them separately. As separate questions. And please refrain from specific nomenclature.. Its difficult to understand for non biologists, instead, explain the requirements with reproducible examples. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: thank you for your efforts, I have made an example to make it simpler, added after my original question above.

Comment: @yysin thank you for updating the question. It is clear now. Continuing further, if you are saying, ` I'd expect to have dendrograms with students 1 & 3 closer to each other than student 2.` then this is not clustering! Why? Because you already know the objects that will/or are supposed to be in a group.

Comment: I wanted just to give you an idea of what I'd expect by giving the results, it's like a positive control if you will to make sure the clustering works correctly. As I mentioned in my original question, I have over 80 patients (students in the second example) that I'd like to cluster, each patient with hundreds of mutations (scores). I would first use a small sample to make sure that it works as it should before applying for the whole dataset.

Comment: @yysin you got to understand that `clustering` essentially means **objects that are forming the groups are unknown beforehand**. Because if the `composition` of a group is known in advance then why are you clustering, for you already know the groups. I think the focus should be on, **how to determine relevant mutation gene combinations?** Here you can use `Multiple Correspondence Analysis (MCA)` for text data which is an alternative to Principal Component Analysis (PCA) to help reduce data dimension as well as extract relevant features.